# Does anyone know how to get visjs to display a node as red if its down?

Tags: vis.js

I currently have a network map that shows all my points and wanted to get assistance on making a node show red when its down.[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cRvFN.png)

I am new to programming/javascript

Comment: Welcome! Can you please provide a [mre]? See [ask] for further guidance. Would it be possible for you to provide a [Stack Snippet](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/11107541)?

Answer (score 0):

Since node is image, we may not be able to make it red/green.
you can create similar image with red/green/grey color which can be replaced based on status on/off/dis, this is how i did in one of my project